# If I have both a start date and end date text field do I have to create 2 different DatePickers?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I have the UIDatePicker working when I click on the start date textfield and on the end date text field but all that it updates is the start date.

Do I need to create to separate Date Pickers or can the one work for the field that you touch?

```
func createDatePicker() {

    // format for picker
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

    // toolbar
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    // bar button item
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)

    startDate.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    endDate.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

    // assigning date picker to text field
    startDate.inputView = datePicker
    endDate.inputView = datePicker

}
```

Comment: Create 2 pickers. One can work but two is more easier so I would go for 2

Comment: Thank you! I figured I would need 2 but just wanting to double check.

Comment: Did you try the code you posted? Does it work with one picker?

Comment: With the code I posted when I tried to set the date for the end date it would just update the start date and leave the end date blank. 

Using the advice from CodingYoshi I created 2 separate pickers (startDate and endDate) and that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually is a way to control **multiple** instances of `UITextField` with **1** `UIDatePicker` instance. One approach would be to keep track of the currently selected `UITextField` through it's `UIView` inherited `.tag` property.

For clarity, use an `enum` to differentiate between the textfields:

```
fileprivate enum TextField: Int {
    case startDateField
    case endDateField
}
```

Define the properties and use a `UIDateFormatter` to translate back and forth between dates and strings:

```
// MARK: - Properties

@IBOutlet weak var startDateTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var endDateTextField: UITextField!
fileprivate var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
fileprivate var currentTextFieldResponder = TextField.startDateField
fileprivate let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .full
    return formatter
}()
```

Configure and connect an action method to the date picker, triggered after each value change: 
*NOTE: the .tag property of the textfields can also be set in SB*

```
// MARK: - View Lifecycle    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // DatePicker base configuration
    datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    // Textfields configuration
    startDateTextField.inputView = datePicker
    startDateTextField.tag = 0
    startDateTextField.delegate = self
    endDateTextField.inputView = datePicker
    endDateTextField.tag = 1
    endDateTextField.delegate = self
}
```

Based on the currently selected `UITextField` property, update the appropriate textfield:

```
// MARK: - Actions    

func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let selectedDateText = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    switch currentTextFieldResponder {
    case .startDateField:
        startDateTextField.text = selectedDateText
    case .endDateField:
        endDateTextField.text = selectedDateText
    }
}
```

Update the `currentTextFieldResponder` property and reset the `datePicker` UI to it's previous selection:

```
// MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    // Just after a text object becomes first responder
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // Update current text responder and reset datePicker's date
        currentTextFieldResponder = TextField(rawValue: textField.tag)!
        if
            let dateText = textField.text,
            let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateText) {
            datePicker.date = date
        }
    }
}
```

As a bonus, setting the `UIDatePicker.date` property will animate the picker columns automatically.

Comment: This works awesome also..... only thing I changed was adding a done button.

In viewDidLoad
//Toolbar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
//Barbutton item
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressedDate))
        toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
        
        startDate.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        endDate.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

and then added this below the Date Picker Actions
func donePressedDate() {        
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        }

Comment: Correct, in your particular situation you want a done button inside a toolbar that that acts as the action. My example was aimed at the question whether you need multiple date pickers when using multiple textfields. And the answer is no, not necessarily.